# How to require generic moved parameters to a Rust method live as long as the object?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm writing a Rust program which includes a Lua interpreter, and I need to save away objects of several types into Lua-managed memory (userdata), so that Lua will call methods on them. Typically they'll be something like `Rc<T>`, and appropriate method wrappers which know the right type will be registered.

If I were only going to accept one type at a time, I can pass objects to the Lua state safely:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    badref: &'a u32,
}

struct LuaState<T> {
    /* ... */
    _foo: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> LuaState<T> {
    fn hide(&mut self, foo: T) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut l = LuaState{_foo: PhantomData};
    {
        let n = 7u32;
        let foo = Foo { badref: &n };
        /* Correctly fails to compile, since l can keep a (hidden)
         * reference to n after its scope ends */
        l.hide(foo);
    }
}
```

I really want `LuaState` to not need the type parameter, but instead have a generic `hide` method:

```
struct LuaState {
    /* ... */
}
impl LuaState {
    fn hide<T>(&mut self, foo: T) {}
}
```

...where it won't compile for any `T` which contains references which don't outlive the `LuaState`, just like I could for a single type at a time above.  I came close with:

```
trait LuaAble<'a> {}
impl<'a> LuaAble<'a> for Foo<'a> {}

struct LuaState<'a> {
    marker: PhantomData<LuaAble<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> LuaState<'a> {
    fn hide<T: LuaAble<'a>>(&mut self, foo: T) {}
}
```

This nearly works; it stops the dangling reference example above, but it's also possible to implement the trait incorrectly:

```
impl<'a, 'b> LuaAble<'b> for Foo<'a> {}
```

This again lets the hidden dangling reference case compile since the lifetimes aren't bound together anymore.

Is there any way to prevent passing into a method by value something which can't live as long as `&self`?  I'm open to any ideas, whether they do something clever and/or terrible with traits, lifetimes, `for<'a>`, restructuring my code, etc.

Comment: *where it won't compile for any `T` which contains references which don't outlive the `LuaState`* — maybe I'm tired, but this seems to have one too many negative conditions. You only want it to compile if all the references stored in `LuaState` outlive the state ("all references in the state are valid while the state exists"), no?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could embed a fake lifetime `'a` in `LuaState<'a>` and require `T: 'a` in `hide()`:

```
struct LuaState<'a> {
    _foo: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> LuaState<'a> {
    fn hide<T: 'a>(&mut self, foo: T) {}
}
```

I am not 100% sure that this is correct, but it seems to work with the example you've given. [(full playpen)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1183e0d34ab1ad560b84&version=stable)

Eliminating the `PhantomData` has the downside that the compiler no longer understands that `LuaState` logically owns an `Rc<T>` for various `T`. This could cause soundness issues if (as it appears to be) dropping a `LuaState` might drop `T` values.

Comment: That looks pretty hopeful and simpler than I'd been fearing! I'll have a play later. I hadn't realized that `T: 'a` is legal. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of `T: 'a` in the Rust Book or reference; it seems to have been defined in this RFC: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0192-bounds-on-object-and-generic-types.md